# Grant document folder access for a Profile

Tags: permissions, profile, sharing, document, folder

I would like to give all users with a certain profile access to a Document Folder I have created. However, when I edit the folder, I am only able to grant access to Roles or Public Groups, I am not able to grant access for all users with a specific profile.

Is there any way to accomplish this, or is the only option to use a Role or Public Group?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the users of that profile to the "Public Group" and then can provide access to the folder for that public group.

Thanks!